# чтение txt файла python

Tags: python, парсер, dataframe, cp1251

Есть файл в txt формате, хотел получить таблицу через pd.read_csv, выходит ошибка

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 17: character maps to <undefined>
```

Пробовал открыть txt файл способом приведенным ниже, возникает проблема

```
file = open('output.txt', encoding='cp1251')
string = file.read().split('\n')[:-1]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 17: character maps to <undefined>
```

Не могли бы помочь?

Comment: `encoding="utf8"` пробовали?

Comment: Спасибо, смог прочитать, теперь остался вопрос как структурировать данные в таблицу.